# Animating circle size in Android

Tags: android, android-studio

I would like to create a circle, center it on the screen and control it's radius.

Task seems easy enough, how can this be accomplished without having to write [OpenGL](http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/draw.html)? Is using [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) the correct way? Or is there anything simpler?

Comment: ..... `canvas.drawCircle()`?

Comment: Create your own View class and override it's onDraw Method for drawing shapes in your View. Try to solve this your own to understand the fundamental of view drawing.

Comment: ... or follow a tutorial like the thermometer gauge,

Comment: You can also use ObjectAnimator to complete animations. http://cogitolearning.co.uk/?p=1404 also you can create a view and set the background of the view to be the circle shape so the view becomes a circle.